# ssh stuck at expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

Tags: ssh

I faced this issue on a server in another country. I changed mtu to values between 1200 and 1500 but nothing changed. I reinstall openssh but nothing happened. please help. tnx.Also forcing HostKeyAlgorithms to one algorithm did not helped. Also tested ssh from the server and it works fine. I think the problem is related to network parameters but I don't know what parameter should i change.

```
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit                                                                                                                                                             > compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit                                                                                                                                                             > compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Comment: Same issue here when trying to connect via the KPN mobile network (Youfone virtual carrier). I did a packet capture between both sides and the packet from the client containing the offered key exchange algorithms gets dropped. The packet shows fragmented in wireshark (captured on the client side, since it never arrived on the server) and, reassembled, has a length of 1536 bytes. This hotspot via a Samsung Android 11 phone I'm using also shows an `64:ff9b::...` address when connecting to plain v4. Victor's fix works for me. Maybe MTU issue after all? Maybe a DPI FW triggering? I'd love to know

Answer (score 8):

I've had the exact same problem and have it solved this way:

**Option 1** (*one-time use*):
At the command line when submitting the SSH connect command, add the `-o KexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521` parameter

**Option 2** (*definitive*):
Add `KexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521` on the corresponding ssh_config file

Comment: Very interesting… The option `-o KexAlgorithms=curve25519-sha256` fixed it for me, but the funny thing is that the option changes nothing. I mean, the algo I provided to this option is the one used by default, and comparing a `-vvv` output with and without the option I see the last lines are the same. But somehow the option makes it work. I think it's a recent bug in patch-release on our older Ubuntu, because it worked before and now it doesn't and given the weirdness with the optoin and I don't see another explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After adding below settings SSH started working

```
[root@RHELSERVER .ssh]# cat /root/.ssh/config
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue and the problem in my case was the destination ssh server was behind a F5 load balancer.
Connections directly to the server worked fine but not through the load balancer.

The resolution was to remove the http profile that was inadvertently assigned on the VIP.